# Jasmine can't find self invoking function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

UPDATE: I've included the JSON config from my index.html file for reference.

I'm using the Jasmine Python module to test my Backbone front-end of a Django app. But I'm having a little trouble getting started.

I'm packaging my Backbone code into separate modules and calling them through an self-invoking function called app (to keep everything out of global scope):

```
var app = (function ($) {
    var config = $('#config'),
        app = JSON.parse(config.text());
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var router = new app.router();
    });
    return app;
})(jQuery);
```

But when I write the following test, I get a response saying app is "undefined":

```
describe('Test app namespace', function () {
    it('should be defined', function () {
        expect(app).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

from index.html:

```
    <script type="text/json" id="config">
        {
            "models": {},
            "collections": {},
            "views": {},
            "router": null,
            "apiRoot": "{% url 'api-root' %}"
        }
    </script>
```

Meanwhile, I can create a test helloworld.js module, run a similar test, and have it pass.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How is `app` provided in the test code?  Is this all on the page, or are you using `RequireJS` or another loader?  I think we need more details on how the tests are constructed in order to help.

Comment: So app.js is located in scope for my src_dir in my jasmine yml. And when I look at the console logs after spinning up the Jasmine Python server, I see jQuery is not defined. I'll update the question with my index.html which has my config JSON.

Comment: OK, I got a passing test by adding jQuery to my helpers directory, and changing my call to app to $(app).

Comment: But now, how do I reference my models or routes or views with Jasmine? For instance, I can't do `var app = $(app); app.models...`. Thoughts?